# MySQL DB, send a multiple data through Python-PHP to the server

Tags: php, python, mysql

I have a Virtual Machine/Web Server with MySQL up and running, and want to receive the data from client hardware that is saved in a .csv file, how can i do a python script to send it? i was recommended requests library from Python to send it and receive it through PHP POST. Problem is ive NEVER used PHP and HTML and so im a bit stuck with the interaction between the 2. Thanks a lot!

sample code is:

```
import csv
import requests

session = requests.Session()
with open('r01a2.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        r = session.post('MyURL', data = {'date: row[0],'value': row[1]})
        print r.text
```

Code on Server side is:

```
    <?php
$formato = "INSERT INTO `datos_pruebas`.`Datos_Edison` (`id`, `date`, `pulse`) VALUES (NULL, '%s', '%f')";
$sql=sprintf($formato,$date,$pulse);
$enlace = mysql_connect('localhost','root','clinichub');
$resultado = mysql_query($sql,$enlace);
$id=NULL;
if(!empty($_POST))
{
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["date"]);
} else { 
echo "gg";
}
```

EDIT2: It finally worked after solutions gave by community and feedback, thanks a lot for your recommendations!

Comment: Shouldn't you do `$_POST["data"]`?

Comment: I did that but didnt change answer :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the post in python uses the correct content-type and verify on the serverside php if $_FILES has an entry.  (i.e. print_r($_FILES) ) should return your file, you won't find it in $_POST.

Comment: Sorry, im a total newbie regarding PHP, can you edit with an example code?

Comment: <?php print_r($_FILES) ?> to start with, it should output the uploaded file metainfo. If you wish to use the contents of the file, the temporary file will be in $_FILES[0]['tmp_name'].

Comment: But im currently not sending the file just now, or maybe i should send it right away? thing is im not even receiving the 'name'

Comment: Answer from server after adding that line is:
HI!Array()

Comment: Shouldn't the python code be more akin to data= {
    'q': '[python]'
    }
r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com', data=data)

Comment: Worked! i was having problems with the format i was sending the data, ill edit the question now

Comment: Okay, so the next step, sending a file - As I mentioned you won't find it in $_POST but in $_FILES, use move_uploaded_file or file_get_contents (both you can find plenty of info on php.net, or here on stack)

Comment: Working on it! help totally appreciated, thanks a lot, third edit already.

Comment: Looks good so far, once you validated that the file is uploaded you can use move_uploaded_file to move it to $file, usage: move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination ) so move_uploaded_file[$FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $file)

Comment: Problem is i still cant succesfully upload the file :/ i really think is my way of writing the code

Comment: That's most likely in the python code part - like: with open('report.xls', 'rb') as f: r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', files={'report.xls': f}), my Python skills aren't up to par tho ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, ill give it some time to keep working